# Boot/Broadcast Receiver reboot issues

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

This is a fairly common question but I'm losing my mind. I think I've been thorough with the requirements. I want a BroadcastReceiver to do something when the phone restarts.

My BroadcastReceiver (for Booting):

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("BootupReceiver", "Refreshing alarms.");
    }
}
```

Within my Manifest's  'manifest' tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Within my Manifest's 'application' tag:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.BootReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

*After deploying the app, I close it, then restart it manually. I don't think the **stopped state** is an issue.*

**Additionally**

I have tried various combinations of this monstrosity:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".receivers.BootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have also tried using the absolute package name in place of the relative one when referencing the receiver name.

I have additionally created a simple, standalone app with nothing but a MainActivity and the above BroadcastReceiver, which is working (infuriatingly).

I've tested this out on a Moto G and a Samsung Galaxy Edge 7.

Is there any known instance where a BootReceiver will not start? Any inclination as to what is going wrong for my code?

I have found a similar question that went [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005641/difficulties-with-android-alarm-manager-boot-complete).

**EDIT**

I have additionally tried using the ads shell to fire the REBOOT intent manually. Still no success.

**EDIT 2**

As requested the full manifest. If you see REDACTED I just removed something potentially confidential.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.REDACTED.REDACTED">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:name=".REDACTEDApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.InitialActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.CreateAccountActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.VideoPlayerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.DisclaimerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.EPWebViewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.EscapePlanActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.EscapeInfoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.EscapeSessionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.EscapeDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="REDACTED"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.RemindersActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".receivers.NotificationsReceiver"/>

    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.BootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

**EDIT 3**

I tried adding another Receiver but have Android Studio generate it. Still no luck.

Used ADB Shell to fire the BOOT_COMPLETED at the app specifically. No success there either.

Comment: please ones verify you have imported all classes and in menifest write class path are mention

Comment: post you entire manifest.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Posted.

Comment: @jiteshmohite I'm certain that the correct classes are imported. I've verified this against a simpler app that contains the same BootReceiver, with the same imports. That app does catch the REBOOT intent. Again, I am certain that the class paths are correct. The autofill does not contradict what I see in the finder view.

Comment: Instead of log try using toast for debugging purpose to reboot

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Toast also fails. I've also tried creating an Intent and starting the Splash activity. No luck with that too.

Comment: Broadcast receiver visually takes time after rebooting to give you broadcast. wait for 15 20 sec after restart of device

Comment: @jiteshmohite I've waited that period and more. Found the solution though. I cleaned the project, rebuilt it and regenerated the APK. Now it works. I dunno why run/build were failing. Would you know if Android Studio caches APKs? Or does build have any known issues? I haven't encountered this issue before where changes, even to the Manifest, were not acquired by the Run/Build process.

Comment: off your Instant Run . There are lot of issue with that.

Comment: @jiteshmohite Funnily enough I had it turned off. This was deploying without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning, rebuilding and regenerating the APK, it is now working. I'm not sure if Studio was caching an old APK, or if I misunderstand/messed up the regular build, but the receiver is now working.